# Can't get tty(1..6) in Linux mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit

Tags: linux-mint, terminal

I would like to know why I can't get the terminals `tty1`,`tty2` etc while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-(<kbd>F1</kbd> ,<kbd>F2</kbd>) etc.I don't know why I can't get these terminals.Is it because my laptop is Toshiba Satellite C55-B5270?

Comment: Many laptops a `Fn` key that you would also have to press to get plain function key behaviour...

Comment: @Kusalananda:That's right.Coud you tell why do I get the GUI at F8 and not F7?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not on Linux Mint and/so I don't know the specifics of what that system is doing with regards to X Windows.

Comment: You have VTs for consoles, one VT for logs, and one for X...The VT order can vary, not that very important. Cannot remember the full details, I do not have a Linux machine with X Windows.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro:Sorry that's because I edited the file `/etc/default/console-setup`.I could see in the file that the line containing active_consoles was `tty[1-6]` and I changed it to `tty[1-7]`  to  know whether it would work.

Comment: Syslog configuration should have hardcoded  a VT, that can be changed for instance from 7 to 10.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro:I have changed it back to `tty[1-6]` and I'm still getting GUI at `tty8` .Could you help me.

Comment: Sorry, only running xorg in FreeBSD. Maybe someone who is running it in Linux can comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many laptops uses the function keys to adjust screen brightness, speaker volume and things like that, they often have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key that you would also have to press to get plain function key behaviour.

Judging from photos of the Toshiba Satellite C55-B5270 keyboard on the net, this key is located to the right of the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

There might also be a <kbd>FnLk</kbd> ("function lock") key, or similar, that you can toggle this behaviour with so that you don't have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> every time.